# How can I add css classes to ChoseType?

Tags: css, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to add some css classes to the ChoiceType Form in my case a radio box (i set the option 'multiple' to false and the option 'expanded' to true).

i don't know which option I Should use i tryed attr and choice_attr but it didn't work.

My problem is:

How to add a css classe to the radio and the text of the radio?

```
  $builder
    ->add('enLigne', ChoiceType::class, [
                    'choices' => $publier,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'radio',
                    ],
'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
                    return ['class' => 'ace input-lg'];
                },
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'label' => 'Publier *',
                    'label_attr' => [
                        "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                        "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                    ]
                ])
```

i want to do a radio box like this:

HTML code:

```
<div class="radio">
     <label>
     <input name="form-field-radio" type="radio" class="ace input-lg">
     <span class="lbl bigger-120"> large radio</span>
     </label></div>
```

Comment: use `add` third parameter and write this `array('attr'=>array('class', 'attr_name'))`

Comment: sorry but, how to use add third parameter ?

Comment: Sorry, missread your code... You already used what I said above... If you need to customize another a specific element within the form, then use css directly... `your_class input[type=radio]`

Comment: sorry, i have not well understood can you put the code.

Comment: Hello, i need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add html attributes using php. Instead add those attributes when rendering the form. Example:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.enLigne, { 'attr': { 'class': 'smaller lighter blue' } } }}
{{ form_end(form)
```

Comment: I have followed the documentation 
but I do not find a solution